# Display Products Attributes label is exported CSV file

Tags: magento2, export, importexport

I want to display product attributes label in exported csv file from backend file.Currently it display product attributes code in exported csv file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can override the getCsvFile function in Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv to handle exporting csv files

```
<preference for=""Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv"" type=""Name\Module\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv"" />
```